# Twilio Task Router

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am using task Router with twilio. I have added three Workers (Users) e.g USER_A,USER_B and USER_C.
Each user has attributes which has name and company.
USER_A and USER_B belongs to same company lets say Company_A and USER_C belongs to
other company lets say COMPANY_C.

I have added code for my voice callback url here as in //example.com/routing.php :

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/xml');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n";

?>
<Response>
  <Gather action="enqueue-call.php" numDigits="1" timeout="10">
    <Say>Press One for Company A</Say>
    <Say>Press Two For Company C</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

And here is my enqueue-call.php :

```
<?php

$digit_pressed = $_REQUEST['Digits'];

if ($digit_pressed == '1') {
  $company = "company_a";
} else {
  $company = "company_c";
}

header('Content-Type: application/xml');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";

?>

<Response>
  <Enqueue workflowSid="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <Task>{"selected_company": "<?php echo $company ?>"}</Task>
  </Enqueue>
</Response>
```

Everything here is completely working.

The requirement in my case is i want to call the selected worker on browser not on worker's mobile.
According to this tutorial : 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/taskrouter/twiml-dequeue-call
They are calling the worker's mobile number.

I have added the agent screen to my each worker as well by following this tutorial :
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/taskrouter/agent-ui-add-project
I have added this code in my agent.php file.

So the requirement is to transfer the incoming call for selected worker on my agent.php

This is my Assigment Callback URL exapmle.com/assignment.php :

```
<?php

$assignment_instruction = [
  'instruction' => 'dequeue',
  'post_work_activity_sid' => '{WA0123401234...}',
  'from' => '+15556667777' // a verified phone number from your twilio account 
];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($assignment_instruction);
```

What should be code for me to add here to call the selected worker which is available ?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are doing a dequeue and it calls the worker's mobile number, then you must have set up the worker's `contact_uri` as the number.

To get it to [call the worker in their browser from a dequeue action you need to set that `contact_uri` to their client name](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/handling-assignment-callbacks#dequeue-call), like this `client:USER_A`.